# Molecular structure correction factor in Mass Flow Controller

Tags: thermodynamics, measurements, flow

This question concerns device called Mass Flow Controller (or Mass Flow Meter). For a video explaining the principle: see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G62ma2IFh9o

These devices are factory calibrated, usually with Nitrogen, but they could be used with other gases or gas mixture. In case we use it with another gas than the one used at calibration (thus having a different thermal capacity), manufacturer provides a formula to make the conversion from the reference gas to the current gas.

### Formula 1

One one hand, Bronkhorst gives below formula in their [General Manual](http://www.bronkhorst.com/files/downloads/manuals_english/917022_general_manual_digital_instruments.pdf)
$$ GCF = \frac {C_{p_1}\rho_1} {C_{p_2}\rho_2} $$

in which

- $c_p$ = specific heat
- $\rho$ = density at normal conditions
- (1) gas calibrated
- (2) gas to be measured

In cas of gas misxture, it extends to a simplified equation given by 
$$ \frac 1 {C_{mix}} = \frac {V_1} {C_1} + \frac {V_2} {C_2} + ... \frac {V_n} {C_n} $$

in which

- $C_{mix}$ = Conversion factor for gas mixture
- $C_{mix}$ = Conversion factor for gas n
- $V_{mix}$ = Volumetric part of gas n in the mixture

### Formula 2

On the other hand, MKS Instruments explains on this page: [FLOW MEASUREMENT & CONTROL
FAQ'S & APPLICATION NOTES](http://www.mksinst.com/docs/UR/FLOWfaq.aspx)
that the GCF (Gas Correction Factor) is defined by

$$ GCF = \frac {0.3106 \sum _{i=1}^n a_i s_i} {\sum _{i=1}^n a_i d_i Cp_i} $$

in which

- $a_i$ is the fractional flow of gas $i$
- $d_i$ is the standard density of gas $i$
- $Cp_i$ is the thermal capacity of gas $i$
- $s_i$ is the molecular structure factor of gas $i$

The constant 0.3106 is there because their MFC are calibrated with Nitrogen.

The 2 formulas give same result if $s_i= 1$

I am wondering why they use $s_i$ and where it does come from?
I've also found [this book (p 52)](https://books.google.ch/books?id=DtLFWKGTNSAC&lpg=PA53&ots=EKvGKayP2H&dq=monatomic%20diatomic%20triatomic%20molecules%20%2B%22correction%20factor%22&hl=fr&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q&f=false) using the molecular structure factor, but still no explanation.

Do you have one?

Comment: Clearly the first formula only applies to a non-mixture, and the second is more generalized. Hot wire or hot film anemometry provides a means of measuring fluid velocity by heat transfer, and this involves the different molecular degrees of freedom in which energy is transferred from the heating element to the gas molecule vibrational modes.$s_i$ might be addressing this factor, but I'm not  sure. Interesting that the second equation does not use a specific heat factor for the reference gas - perhaps that's in the factor 0.3106. Call MKS and ask top speak to a design engineer.

Comment: @docscience yes, it appears that 0.3106 is a product of standard density and thermal capacity of nitrogen (in units used by MKS).

Comment: "Molecular structure" correction factor is an empirical factor which compensates for differences in variation of the specific heat with temperature for different types of gas molecules (i.e. monatomic, diatomic, tri-atomic, etc). Taken from [this paper](http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/30/048/30048008.pdf).

Comment: The perturbations in specific heat, I suspect, has to do with the fact that different shapes/sizes of molecules have different vibrational modes, and therefore store different amounts of heat energy. That probably causes the perturbations in the heat 'constants'. There may also be work in statistical mechanics or quantum mechanics that approaches this problem in a more theoretic and exact manner. Thanks for the link - a useful reference for my own work.

Comment: Thanks gigacyan for the reference to your paper. It was the kind of paper I was searching. It makes me also realize that it's admitted that MFC could make up to 10% of error of the gas flowing through the MFC is not the reference gas...which surprises me a lot...but ok, that's it.